# Seeking information on the accuracy of average Fuel Consumption shown in Instrument Console?

Tags: motorcycle, fuel-consumption, fuel-injection, wheel-speed-sensor, vehicle-speed-sensor

If the speed shown in a motorcycle's instrument cluster is off by let's say ~5 km/h relative to the actual speed, can we say that the average fuel consumption it shows is also prone to show wrong values because average fuel consumption is a function of summation of fuel used over a given distance and the source to measure the distance got to be the same for current speed shown as well as measuring the fuel consumption. Right !?

Comment: Yes, that's how it works, assuming the fuel consumption is calculated from the same sensor (usually on the transmission output shaft,) and not a separate cable to the front wheel, or other such device.

Comment: The speedo is not supposed to under-read, so the manufacturers will calibrate it half-way between the legal limits so it over-reads. Of course they always want to exaggerate fuel consumption so there is no reason why they should make that accurate. Treat the gauge as a guide.